# Connecting arduino to an android app which uses libgdx (using Bluetooth)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, libgdx

so i'm trying to do something a little unusual, it's just for fun. I have a game i created using libgdx, it consists of a ship that can shoot. What i want to do is to use some external push buttons to move it. The push buttons send signals to arduino, which in turn sends them to an HC-05 bluetooth module. however i'm very doubtful about the android side of things. What i did basically was the following:

Because i'm working on libgdx i created an interface called BluetoothDude, with three methods setBluetooth() (which will set the bluetooth for the particular platform),String whatIsTheMessage() (which will tell you what's been sent to the phone), and  boolean isActive(), to know if the bluetooth is active of course.

The MainGame will receive a BluetoothDude so that particular classes like Ship have access to the Message and are able to react to it.

Then i did the particular implementation of Bluetooth for android, in the setBluetooth() i followed this guide very closely: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

i'm sure it is connecting properly, because when it creates the socket it can print "connection success with HC-05" (it will only print that if the method which creates the sockets, which i called BTConnect() returns true).

The problem seems to be in reading the data, the code i'm using is

```
   private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private Handler handler;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket,Handler mHandler) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        handler = mHandler;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

i made an object of this class in setBluetooth like this

```
 if (device != null) {
        if (BTconnect()) {
            isActive = true;
            connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket,handler);
            System.out.println("connection success with" + device.getName() + " message: " + message );

        }
```

i have a lot of doubts 
first what is the target here, the mHandler was created in BluetoothDude, so is that the target?, second i'm quite sure the thread isn't even running because if i put a line like System.out.println("run") inside run() it doesn't show me the line like a trillion times in the logcat when the app is executed. What is wrong with it, i hope you can help me, i'm not very experienced at all of this, and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see if this is the case from your code but if you are calling platform specific methods, that should be done in the platform specific project subproject.

For more information on how to do that you can check out this page :
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

So if your LibGDX game has a function say, "setBluetooth" each platform will have its own implementation of said method. That will differ when you compile for Android or iOS.

If you try to call platform specific code in your core game probably won't work.

Hope it helps, maybe you have already done that in which case you can ignore my comment.